# noise-free Gaussian Process likelyhood

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, bayesian

I am learning Gaussian Process reading [GPML](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters).
I am a bit confused with understanding the Bayesian analysis.

Let consider the standard linear regression model with "Gaussian noise", i.e,
$$
f(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{x}^T\textbf{w}, \qquad y = f(\textbf{x}) + \epsilon, \qquad \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_n^2)
$$
where $\textbf{w}, \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that
$$
\epsilon = y - f(\textbf{x}) = y - \textbf{x}^T\textbf{w} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_n^2)
$$
and the p.d.f. of $\epsilon$ is 
$$
p_\epsilon(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_n}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}{2\sigma_n^2}\right). 
$$
Therefore, given $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{w}$, the p.d.f. of $y$ would be
$$
p_{y\mid \textbf{x}, \textbf{w}}(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_n}\exp\left(-\frac{(z-\textbf{x}^T\textbf{w})^2}{2\sigma_n^2}\right). 
$$
It then follows from the Bayes' rule that
$$
p_{\textbf{w}\mid y, \textbf{x}}(w) = \frac{p_{y\mid \textbf{x},\textbf{w}}(z)\cdot p_{\textbf{w}}(w)}{p_{y\mid \textbf{x}}(z)}.
$$

**Question:** In the noise-free setup, how one can derive the posterior distribution $p_{\textbf{w}\mid y, \textbf{x}}(w)$?
It seems that in the noise-free setup, $y$ is completely determined by $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{w}$. Thus 
$$p_{y\mid \textbf{x},\textbf{w}}(z) = \delta_{\{z=\textbf{x}^T\textbf{w}\}}(z),
$$ a point distribution.
Then this gives
$$
p_{\textbf{w}\mid y, \textbf{x}}(w) = \frac{\delta_{\{z=\textbf{x}^T\textbf{w}\}}(z)}{P_{\textbf{w}}(\textbf{x}^T\textbf{w}=z \mid \textbf{x})}p_{\textbf{w}}(w) ?
$$
(actually, not 100% sure about this).

At this point, I don't see how the Bayeian approach is somehow useful in the noise-free senario. Or Is Bayeian approach based on the assumption of the presence of the noise?

Any comments/answers/suggestions would be very appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The noise free set up described in the book is for the Gaussian process model, which is different from the Bayes' one at the beginning of the section. You could take the limit of the maximum a-posteriori estimate as $\sigma_n \to 0$  to get a noise free estimate of the weight space model.

Comment: @DanielBeale Thanks for your comment. I am trying to understand it without taking the limit. I believe it should result in the same conclusion.

Comment: You may be able to reach a similar solution, but the assumptions are not the same in the Gaussian process. Most importantly the GP assumes that there is non-zero covariance between each of the known inputs. The $\epsilon$'s are i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_n)$ in the linear regression example.

Comment: With regard to your point about the limit. It would be possible to view a distribution as a function which maps to $\mathbb{RP}^2$. The first dimension containing the probability density, and the second containing the integral.